# Trying to get Nav menu and logo to align within the grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a responsive Nav menu for a website. I changed the header image into an image slider however now on the index.html page the nav menu is no longer aligned to the websites grid.

In the 'about', 'services' and contact pages the menu is positioned perfectly. 
In the index.html page I have css code to position the navbar and logo position:absolute; but the rest of navs on the other page are position relative.

I want all the nav menus on each page to align the same so there is no obvious difference when the user changes pages. It may not be obvious on small screens but when you compare the index and about pages on a mobile device it is obvious the nav is not in the correct grid.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Here is a link to the live site 
http://shaneogrady.me/navtest/

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> HELLO </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="keywords" content=""><script> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,800,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
    <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
         new WOW().init();
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/move-top.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(".scroll").click(function(event) {        
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},900);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="home" class="banner a-banner">
    <div class="container" style="  position: relative; z-index: 5; top: 0%; left: 5%;">
        <div class="head-logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="top-nav">
            <span class="menu"><img src="images/menu.png" alt=""></span>
            <ul class="nav1">
                <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><a href="contact.html">Contact<i><img src="images/nav-but5.png" alt=""/></i></a></li>
                <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><a href="services.html">Services<i><img src="images/nav-but3.png" alt=""/></i></a></li>
                <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><a href="about.html">About<i><img src="images/nav-but2.png" alt=""/></i></a></li>
                <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom active"><a href="index.html">Home<i><img src="images/nav-but1.png" alt=""/></i></a></li>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </ul>
            <script>
                $( "span.menu" ).click(function() {
                    $( "ul.nav1" ).slideToggle( 300, function() {});
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="carousel fade-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000" id="bs-carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item slides active">
            <div class="slide-1">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="hero">
                <hgroup>
                    <h1>Batman</h1>        
                    <h3>Batman</h3>
                </hgroup>
                <div class="see-button">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg see-button hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" href="about.html" role="button">See More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item slides">
            <div class="slide-2">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="hero">        
                <hgroup>
                    <h1>Superman</h1>        
                    <h3>Superman</h3>
                </hgroup>       
                <div class="see-button">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg see-button hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" href="about.html" role="button">See More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item slides">
            <div class="slide-3">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="hero">        
                <hgroup>
                    <h1>Spiderman</h1>        
                    <h3>Spiderman</h3>
                </hgroup>
                <div class="see-button">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg see-button hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" href="services.html" role="button">See More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background:#fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
body a {
  transition: 0.5s all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s all;
  -o-transition: 0.5s all;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s all;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s all;
}
.banner{
  background: url(../images/banner2.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px #eeece9;
  min-height: 855px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.head-logo{
  float: left;
}
.head-logo a {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 3.5em;
}
.top-nav{
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
}
.top-nav ul{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.top-nav ul  li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  margin-right: .4em;
  display:block;
  float: right;
  line-height:38px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
}
.top-nav ul  li.active{
    background: #5abc5e;
}
.top-nav ul li a{
color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: .4em;
  float: left;
  padding: 3em 0em 3em 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 79%;
}
.top-nav ul li a i{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-style: italic;
}
.top-nav ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}

/********************************/
/*       Fade Bs-carousel       */
/********************************/
.fade-carousel {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item {
    height: 100vh;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators > li {
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #f39c12;
    border-color: #f39c12;
    opacity: .7;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators > li.active {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}

/********************************/
/*          Hero Headers        */
/********************************/
.hero {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.75);
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
          -ms-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
           -o-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
              transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
}
.hero h1 {
    font-size: 6em;    
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item .hero {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item.active .hero {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;    
}

/********************************/
/*            Overlay           */
/********************************/
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #080d15;
    opacity: .3;
}

/********************************/
/*       Slides backgrounds     */
/********************************/
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1, 
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2,
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1 {
  background-image: url(../images/banner2.jpg); 
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2 {
  background-image: url(../images/squad.jpg);
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  background-image: url(../images/roadside.jpg);
}

/********************************/
/*          Media Queries       */
/********************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 980px){
    .hero { width: 980px; }    
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
    .hero h1 { font-size: 4em; }    
}

/* Sweep To Bottom */
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom {
  display: inline-block;                                           
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -ms-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        -o-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
    -o-transition-property: color;
  -moz-transition-property: color;
  -ms-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #5abc5e;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -o-transform: scaleY(0);
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    -o-transition-property: transform;
  -moz-transition-property: transform;
  -ms-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
      -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:hover, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:focus, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:hover:before, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:focus:before, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.banner-bottom-grids{
    margin: 5em 0;
}
.banner-bottom-left{
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  margin: 0;
}
.banner-bottom-left h3{
  color: #000;
  font-size: 37px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.banner-bottom-left h5{
  color: #969696;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 1em 0;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}
.banner-bottom-left h5 span{
    display:block;
}
.banner-bottom-left p{
color: #333333;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.banner-bottom-right img{
    width:100%;
}
.see-button{
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.see-button a{
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1em 4em;
  outline: none;
  background: #393939;
  border: none !important;
  border-radius:0;
  }
.jumbotron.banner-bottom-left {
  background: none;
}
/*------------------ Slider Part starts Here----------*/
#slider2,
#slider3 {
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.rslides_tabs {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
  font-size: 18px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
  max-width: 540px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.rslides_tabs li {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
.rslides_tabs a {
  width: auto;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 9px 20px;
  height: auto;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline;
}
.rslides_tabs li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.rslides_tabs .rslides_here a {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.events {
  list-style: none;
}
.callbacks_container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.callbacks {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.callbacks li {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.callbacks img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
}
.callbacks .caption {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: none;
    top: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}
.callbacks_nav {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    top: 52%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 3;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 61px;
    width: 55px;
    background: transparent url("../images/themes.png") no-repeat left top;
    margin-top: -65px;
}
.callbacks_nav:active {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
.callbacks_nav.next {
  left: auto;
  background-position: right top;
  right: 0;
}
#slider3-pager a {
  display: inline-block;
}
#slider3-pager span{
  float: left;
}
#slider3-pager span{
    width:100px;
    height:15px;
    background:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:30em;
    opacity:0.6;
}
#slider3-pager .rslides_here a {
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius:30em;
  opacity:1;
}
#slider3-pager a {
  padding: 0;
}
#slider3-pager li{
    display:inline-block;
}
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.rslides li{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.rslides img {
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
  width:100%;
}
.callbacks_tabs{
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 78%;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 45%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.slider-top{
    text-align: center;
    padding:10em 0;
}
.slider-top h1{
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:48px;
    color:#010101;
}
.slider-top p{
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:1em 7em;
    color:#010101;
}
.slider-top ul.social-slide{
    display:inline-flex;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try rebuilding your css from scratch instruction by instruction and see what is changing something. If a change doesn't apply, try adding !important at the end (like so :`{ width : 30% !important;}`), sometimes Bootstrap is a bit possessive.
Maybe throwing a `position : absolute ; right :0; top:0;` in the `.top-nav` and building from there would help do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> An element with `position: absolute` is positioned relative to the
>   nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the
>   viewport, like fixed)
>
> `position: absolute` allows an element to be positioned with respect
>   to a containing block using `left`, `right`, `top` or `bottom` (the containing
>   block is the nearest ancestor node with a position of relative,
>   absolute or fixed).

To fix it just add `left: 0` and `right: 0` to `.container` this will make the div stretch to document width.

Here a minimal snippet example to illustrate (without using `left`, `right`):

```css
div.relative {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #8AC007;
}
div.absolute {
    position: absolute;    
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">This
    <div>element has position: relative;
        <div class="absolute">This
            <div>element has position: absolute;</div>
        </div>
```

Now with `left: 0`, `right: 0`

```css
div.relative {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #8AC007;
}
div.absolute {
    position: absolute;    
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">This
    <div>element has position: relative;
        <div class="absolute">This
            <div>element has position: absolute;</div>
        </div>
```

[Check this out to full information](http://www.sitepoint.com/css-sizing-absolute-position/)